# Heroku and Github log in issues, (Heroku.account = work, No such account: work)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, github

I am having trouble pushing and logging into Heroku. 
When attempting to log in, it renders the error;

> **No such account: work**

So, looking at my github config list I see that it states;

> **heroku.account=work**

I can't find the correct method to change these; how to revert these two back to their default settings or personal account?

I managed to sort this by firstly deleting the heroku account in the git config --edit file, then was able to go heroku accounts:add personal --auto then setting this as a default using heroku accounts:default personal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats coming from the Heroku Accounts plugin (https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-accounts) which allows you to switch accounts. Once reinstalled you probaby need to do `heroku accounts:add work` and enter your work credentials and it should start working.

Comment: I have just tried that and it's response is still no such account: work, shall i uninstall the plugin? actually this is the response with almost every command...

Comment: thanks are best awarded by marking question as answered and upvoting answer :)

Comment: ah im getting it now...fortunately not reputable enough to upvote yet...sigh

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the existing account credentials by `rm -rf ~/.heroku/plugins/heroku-accounts` and then type `heroku login` enter your credentials.. okay now.